# Character limit - Joomla (Article Content)

Tags: joomla, maxlength

I am stuck working on a gallery, which uses 3 columns and 1 row multiplied alot of times to show a simple and clear gallery.

The problem comes when after publishing, the max-length of articles cut the content, but I can't find the config where I can change it.

Comment: What do you mean by max-length?

Answer (score 1):

This is problem with your template style(or gallery plugin/module gallery style), you have to edit your css file.

Best way is to check gallery with Firebug (mozzila add-in), make necessary changes and then overwrite  default style.

Be careful with your updates, that do not overwrite your style.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but seems like the problem there's that I have a max character wich I cannot modify (or I dont know where to do it)

Answer (score 1):

It was a problem with MySQL.

I just changed "Text" value for "LongText" (on MySQL), so that way I can use a large amount of characters on the same script.